# rvest: cannot extract node using html_nodes with xpath and a regular expression

Tags: r, regex, xpath, rvest, stringr

I am doing some webscraping with rvest and stringr and having a problem I could not yet find a solution for on stackoverflow.

I want to extract a specific node that contains a combination of words and numbers over a large number of documents.

Because the information is at a different node in each of the documents, I want to locate it via using the `[contains(text() '')]` method from xpath and entering a regular expression `'\\d{1,4}'` here.

The following example illustrates where the code does not work or where I am doing it wrong:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(rstudioapi)


rep_url <- "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eintracht_Braunschweig"


parsed <- read_html(rep_url)
```

I want to extract "15. Dezember 1895", but when I use an xpath combined with a regex `[contains(text() '\\d{1,4}')]` I get an empty character, where I should get two character strings. The code only works when I enter the concrete numbers.

```
number <- parsed %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[7]/td[contains(text(), '\\d{1,4}')]") %>%
  html_text()

number
>character(0)

number <- parsed %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[7]/td[contains(text(), '1895')]") %>%
  html_text()
number
>[1] "15. Dezember 1895\n"
```

What am I missing out here? What do I do wrong such that I cannot combine this regular expression with my xpath?

The above example illustrates the problem, and as there are probably other ways to extract the "15. Dezember 1895", I emphasise that Rit is important that I find a way to combine xpath with regex successfully.

Some advice is much appreciated since I could not yet find a similar problem on stackoverflow or other webpages.

Best regards

Mio

Answer (score 0):

To use regular expressions I think you need to use `matches()` instead of `contains`. However, `matches()` doesn't seem to work for `rvest`.

Would something like this work instead ?

```
library(rvest)
rep_url <- "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eintracht_Braunschweig"
parsed <- read_html(rep_url)

parsed %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[7]/td") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  grep('\\d{1,4}', ., value = TRUE)
#[1] "15. Dezember 1895\n"
```